# Index Out Of Bounds Exception when trying to read from file into ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to read a series of integers from a file into an ArrayList but when accessing numbers.get(0), I get the Out of Bounds Exception, presumably because nothing has been written to the list.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void Numbers() throws IOException{

  File file = new File("Numbers.txt");
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

  while (inputFile.hasNext()){

    numbers.add(inputFile.nextInt());
  }

    inputFile.close();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more code snippets if needed.

Comment: I don't see a line of code that says `numbers.get(0)`. Where is this code?

Comment: Is the file actually being opened?

Comment: The first token in the file can't be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: I call it in another method like: int lowest = numbers.get(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its trying to read the token as `int` and comes out with exception. Try this:

```
try{
   File file = new File("Numbers.txt");
   Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
   while (inputFile.hasNext()){
    String next = inputFile.next();
    try{
        numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(next));
     }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
       //not a number, ignore it
     }
   }
 }catch(IOException ioe){
      ioe.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: After fixing the constructor format I get the error unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown as stated above. I have not learned how to catch yet unfortunately. Is this what I need to learn to alleviate this error?

Comment: Consider using `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()`.

Comment: @Randallsm83 Updated the answer with `IOException` handling. Please put the code inside your constructor and remove the `throws IOException` from declaration.

Comment: @Randallsm83: In addition, please make sure you perform a size check before `int lowest = numbers.get(0);` otherwise you will again get `IndexOutOfBoundException` if your constructor couldn't read your file and `numbers` list wasn't populated.

Comment: Perfect! I know the problem now is my book didn't touch on catching the exception which is exactly what it need. Thank you everyone so much for the quick help!

Comment: @Randallsm83: Good. If there are still any issues, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

One likely problem is that you have declared the method as

```
public void Numbers() throws IOException
```

This is a method called `Numbers` which returns `void` and throws `IOException`. Note that this is **not** a constructor, which you might intend it to be, because you have declared a return type. If you are calling `numbers.get(0)` in another method of this same class. This `Numbers()` method is probably not called explicitly if you expect it to be called automatically as a constructor.

Comment: I did intend this to be the constructor so it sounds like this is the problem. Now that I have removed the return type I get the error, Error: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Comment: Btw, this is the line im getting the error on: public static void main(String[] args){
       Numbers n = new Numbers();

Comment: @Randallsm83 You need to do exactly what the error message says: either catch the IOException which your constructor throws or declare `main()` to throw it.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't learned that just yet but I am going to right now!